# How to print dataframe properly into Excel file

Tags: excel, dataframe, matrix

When using this script, the data effectively is pasted to the right of column X, but is deleting all information to the left of this column and from start_row. I would expect the data to the left of this column to remain as is.

I tried the below script, but it always deletes data to the left of the set column:

```
from openpyxl import Workbook, load_workbook  # necessary to print into an excel
from openpyxl.utils.dataframe import dataframe_to_rows

start_row = row_number
start_column = X

for r in dataframe_to_rows(temp_df, index=False, header=False):
    col_idx = start_column
    for cell_value in r:
        ws.cell(row=start_row, column=col_idx).value = cell_value
        col_idx += 1
    start_row += 1
```